# Replication between local PouchDB instances

Tags: pouchdb

Is it possible to have multiple local PouchDB instances on different devices sync with each other when there is no internet connectivity, say within an intranet?

If this is possible, I assume each device would need to have its database accessible via a URL that can be pointed to in code as per the PouchDB Replication [docs](https://pouchdb.com/guides/replication.html)?

A follow-up question would be can all devices then sync to a remote CouchDB instance when internet becomes available?

Comment: You must have a server, with network connectivity. Whether that is over the "Internet" or not, is unimportant.

Comment: Thanks @Flimzy, I'll consider the approach of having a local server that all devices can sync to, and the server itself syncs to the cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I regularly replicate between virtual hosts in a single server and also with a  CouchDB in the cloud.

As long as you can HTTP the database you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks @Martin Bramwell, ideally I would like two tablets to sync their PouchDB instances with each other, but this would require making the databases on the device accessible via an HTTP url. I'm not sure how to go about this, or if it is even possible?

Comment: I believe you would have to look into WebRTC, but I know nothing about it.  That's if you need to go 100% serverless. If all clients can sync with each other through an intermediary server, you would have the appearance of P2P sync, if not the reality.

Comment: An intermediary server sounds like a good approach, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can sync two local PouchDBs if they are on the same device.

If they are on different devices you need some kind of server to establish the connection between them. This could be a local CouchDB or a PouchServer.

I don't know your use case but if you make something like an Electron app you can run a PouchServer within it. This would allow you to sync local devices.

This works on all devices that can run nodejs. We even got it to work ir a Cordava app but it was not production stable so we gave offline syncing up for now.